# Why does not ; equivalent to the eol?

Tags: scala, separator, postfix-operator

Here is [the code that compiles](http://scastie.org/20667) as intended

```
  def coarse_grained: Int = {
    def fib: Int = List(1,2) sum ;
    fib
  }
```

and [one which does not](http://scastie.org/20666)

```
  def coarse_grained: Int = {
    def fib: Int = List(1,2) sum
    fib
  }
```

The only difference is `;` after the `sum`.

Comment: Yes, the answers are suitable but question is specific about the types. I do not duplicate the question about the types. I ask a general one. So, my formulation must be preferred (or preserved at least).

Comment: There's nothing different here with the types. You're invoking `List[T].sum` in a suffix notation position, but the compiler is inferring it as infix notation, thus trying to do `List(1,2).sum(fib)`, which makes the `fib` method return `Unit`, and not `Int`.

Comment: In other words, it's a parsing thing. Types are irrelevant.

Comment: Whatever you do, compiler detects the errors by type mismatches. So, every parsed but failed to compile program is ascribed to type error category, even if type error comes out of a wrong parser job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, `List(2,6,9).drop(1)` can also be written as `List(2,6,9) drop 1`. In fact, it can also be written like this.

```
List(2,6,9) drop
1
```

The compiler keeps looking for the final argument, even past a newline.  So if you want to do this `List(1,2).sum` like this `List(1,2) sum`, you'll need to use the semicolon `;` to tell the compiler to stop looking for the final argument.  It's not coming.

Comment: Instead of adding semi, it's more usual to add a blank line (extra newline).

Comment: @som-snytt, thanks. I didn't know that.  In truth, I would never use either one of them (semicolon or blank line).  The dot syntax is much clearer and safer.